# find command en several parent directory trees

Tags: find

Want to use the find command on a three different directory trees.

I currently work on each parent directory with `.`

```
find . -type f -name "*.flac" -exec rename 's/--/-/g' {} \;
```

Want to apply the find to three directories `/media/bard/repo01/`, `/media/bard/repo02/` and `/media/bard/repo03/`.

Comment: This should work: `find /media/bard/repo01/ /media/bard/repo02/ /media/bard/repo03/ -type f ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
find /media/bard/repo0[1-3] -type f -name "*.flac" -exec rename 's/--/-/g' {} \;
```

Using a `glob`:

```
man bash | less +/'^ *Pattern Matching\s*$'
```